# www. redirect only working for homepage

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have used this in .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^customlogoshop.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.customlogoshop.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

However, only my homepage `customlogoshop.com` gets redirected to `www.customlogoshop.com`. All my other pages won't redirect.

Updated:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^customlogoshop.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.customlogoshop.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

What these rules are doing is redirecting .php to a non-extension URL. Trailing slashes are redirected to non-trailing slash URL's.

Comment: Could you please post your entire .htaccess file?  It looks like you need to specify `RewriteEngine On`.

Comment: Updated entire .htaccess

Comment: I do not know the syntax of this file too well.  But how about moving the www redirection code to the top of the file?  (immediately below the `RewriteEngine on` statement)  It seems like doing that would eliminate some variables.

Answer (score 0):

Put the redirection rule above everything else.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^customlogoshop.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.customlogoshop.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```